# Why cant i make '0.00000001' to a float/decimal?

Tags: javascript, numbers

I am working on a cryptocurrencie application where i have to convert a string looking like this '0.00000001' to a number float/decimal looking like this 0.00000001

I have tried

toPrecision()

parseFloat()

parseInt()

Number()

toFixed(8)

'0.00000001' * 1

The results will typically look something like this  5.3e-7

Is there nothing that can be done in this particular case?

Comment: It is a number. run 5.3e-7 * 1000

Comment: Do not use floating point math for currency. There are numeric math libraries designed to handle money.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any good ones in mind ?